# How to enable/validate date input only from current date to 50 years before in Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, validation, momentjs

I am using moment.js. I want to restrict the user son that he can only select a date which is from current date to 50 years before.
In short, i just want that user's date of birth cannot be more than 50 years. So, from the current date, only ranges before the 50 years should only be there.
How can i do so? please guide me.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ the `.diff` functions can be used with the 'years' argument to check the difference in years between 2 dates. Just gotta check if that's <= 50

Answer (score 1):

So you have to calculate 50 years back date first
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

```
fiftyYearsBackDate = moment().subtract(50, "years")
```

Get user Selected date

```
userDate = new Date()
```

Create moment object from that and do query
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/

```
moment(userDate).isAfter(fiftyYearsBackDate)
```

this will return `boolean` that you can use to show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate the `difference` in years between now and the birthdate, and check if it's bigger than 50.

```
const birthDate = '1970-01-01'
const yearsDiff = moment().diff(birthDate, 'years');
```

If you want to get the difference of years in decimal:

```
const yearsDiff = moment().diff(birthDate, 'years', true);
```

The `yearsDiff`  will contain the difference,  so you can do an `if` check on it to see if it's bigger than 50.

Official docs for this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 1):

By using moment js you can easily get past and future dates like this -

```
const past = moment().subtract(50, 'years'); // To past
const future = moment().add(50, 'years'); // Back to future
```

Finally

```
const today = moment();
moment(today).isAfter(past, 'year'); // return: true || false
```

The reference site URL is - https://everyday.codes/javascript/how-to-format-date-in-javascript-with-moment-js/

Comment: I had used....   max={moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
By doing that, all the future dates got disabled in the general date picker of bootstrap. But, all the past dates are coming. Can i do anything by doing which dates before 1972 also get disabled in the date picker??

Comment: Moment js and datepicker both are different so for datepicker you should check - https://reactdatepicker.com/ here you can user minDate and Maxdate show date validation.

Answer (score 1):

Without moment.js you can test if the birthdate is less than today minus 50 years:

```
birthdate < new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 50);
```

Example use:

```js
let testDates = [
  new Date(1970,0,1), // 1 Jan 1970
  new Date(2000,0,1)  // 1 Jan 2000
].forEach(date => console.log(
  `More than 50 years ago?\n` +
  `${date.toDateString()}: ${date < new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 50)}`
));
```

The only behaviour to check is around 29 Feb. Some places move the birthday to 28 February in non–leap years and others to 1 March.